# unpacking a list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, unpack

Somewhere I saw a piece of code where you can unpack a list in a for loop. Let's say that I have a list:

```
row = ['001', '15\n', '963789', '40\n', '741239', '80\n', '985697', '80\n', '854698', '35\n', '965874', '10\n']
```

what would be the for loop to unpack the list. I saw something similar to:

```
for emp_id,pay_rate,job1,hours_worked1,job2,hours_worked2,job3,hours_worked3,job4,hours_worked4,job5,hours_worked5 in row:
```

what's the correct syntax to unpack this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That only really works if you have a nested structure. For example:

```
l = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]

for a,b,c in l:
    print a,b,c

[OUTPUT]
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

If you have a flat list like this:

```
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

You can do:

```
one, two, three, four, five = l2
```

Comment: What you have is not a nested list

Answer (score 0):

Simple assignment:

```
emp_id,pay_rate,job1 = ['001', '15\n', '963789']
```